# Route not triggering in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4.2, thephpleague

I have a folder with images in it at `example.com/img/`, and at the same time I have a route

```
get('img/{path}', 'ImageController@output');
```

But when I try going to `example.com/img/someimagepath` and if image name is `someimagepath` I get that image instead of firing route above.

Is there a way to make it fire route instead of requesting a file?

To be precise, I'm using https://github.com/thephpleague/glide Glide library

Comment: This is because your web server will take existing paths over virtual paths. Let us know what server software you use and show us your config so we can help you further.

Comment: I think what is happening is the server config has directives that checks if a file exists and delivers that if it does, otherwise it invokes the framework.

Comment: did the answer below solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because the server is looking in the `public` folder, finding the `img` directory, and serving the image from there instead of loading `public/index.php`. If `index.php` is not loaded, laravel is not loaded, so the routes won't work.

Either rename the folder in your public directory, or rename your route. You cannot have them both referencing `img`

I'd keep the directory the same, and rename your route:

```
get('images/{path}', 'ImageController@output');
```

or maybe prefix your routes if you really like `img` as a segment:

```
get('app/img/{path}', 'ImageController@output');
```

Basically, your routes cannot follow any path hierachry in `public`. The way the sever knows to load laravel is if it cannot find a directory or file in `public` that matches the URI, it loads `index.php`. If it does find a directory or file path matching the URI, it will serve that instead.

From `public\.htaccess`. Basically saying if the request does not match a file or directory, load index.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Yes, this worked, but it lead me to next issue. Now I'm getting an error

`NotReadableException in Decoder.php line 21:
Unable to read image from file (/tmp/random).`

Comment: that sounds more like a new issue. Your image library is obviously storing processed images in that file and they can't be accessed. You'll need a new question for that I think.